# Two public static variables with different values

Tags: java

Please let me know if this is duplicate.. searched but couldn't find this exact question in stack overflow.
Say we have

```
public class A{
      public static String s="Arnab";
    }

 public class B{
     public static String s="Someone else";
    }



public class C{

    public void myMethod(){
         System.out.println(s);
      }
    }
```

What will the syso in myMethod() of class C print?
And why?

**UPDATE:** Oops sorry my bad.. didnt realise was not using the class name (like A.s)
Wish I could delete the answer :(

Comment: Compilation Error. You should use class Name for using 's'. Also output depends on which class name you are using. And you cannot include SOP directly inside class.

Comment: Compilation error. Have you tried to compile the code?

Comment: Additionally, you can not declare 3 public class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ran the code you would get :

```
   error: cannot find symbol
             System.out.println(s);
```

That is because `s` is not defined in class C, if you want to access `s` of class A then use `A.s`. Similarly `s` of class B would be `B.s`.

Eg : (for `s` of `class B`)

```
public void myMethod(){
         System.out.println(B.s);
      }
```

Output : `Someone else`

(You would get whatever you assign to `s` in `class B`)

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot access those variable directly. You will have to provide class name too.
2. You cannot write a statement directly in class. You will have to use a block or function

.

```
public class C {
    public static void main(String...args){
        System.out.println(A.s);
        System.out.println(B.s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see many mistakes in your post.

1) Declare only that class public in which you have defined **main** method.

2) Always define statements other than initialization and declaration inside  methods.

3) Always use class name or object name for using static variable outside of the class where it is declared.

4) You can only use instances of class to use instance variables(which are not static).

**Now regarding your query:** No these variables are not duplicate the output depends on which class you are using for that variable.

```
    class A{
              public static String s="Arnab";
            }

         class B{
             public static String s="Someone else";
            }

     public class C{
            public static void main(String [] ar){
              System.out.println(A.s); // gives:Arnab
System.out.println(B.s); // gives:Someone Else
            }
        }
```